# Disable browser adding overflow:hidden on touch screen enabled devices

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, touch

I'm having an issue with browsers (maybe just Chrome) adding css rules on touch enabled devices.

On a website we've created for a client (to be used exclusively in Chrome), when accessing from their ultrabooks, the scroll bars disappear on elements on the page that had them.  The client is still using these as regular laptops, thus there is no need to remove the scrolling.  The issue appears to be the fact that because they have touch screens, the browser automatically adds these css rules to certain elements:

```
overflow: hidden;
width: auto;
```

This removes the scroll bars, and breaks the site because many elements can no longer be interacted with fully.

I've done some research on this and haven't been able to find much (all the results I keep getting are regarding people wanting overflow:hidden on mobile). 
I was hoping that there was some setting in Chrome to disable this, but I haven't been able to find anything.  I also know its possible to add some forced CSS rules... but that might just open up another can of worms.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer.

In Chrome, go to
chrome://flags

About 1/3 the way down, there is a setting called ‘Enable touch events’.

Chrome Description:

> Enable touch events : Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS
>
> Force touchscreen support to always be enabled or disabled, or to be enabled when a touchscreen is detected on startup (Automatic, the default). #touch-events

Select ‘Disabled’ in the drop down.  After they make the selection, a button will appear at the bottom of the window that says ‘Relaunch Now’.  After clicking on that, Chrome will restart.  Scroll bars should now appear.